# Explode function is not working properly

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, explode

I am getting output from the database which is working. Below array displaying the proper output.

```
 $get_elements = array(
        'student_elements' => $row->student_elements, 
        'address_elements' => $row->address_elements,  
        'marketing_elements' => $row->marketing_elements, 
        'office_use_elements' => $row->office_use_elements, 
 );
```

Getting output

```
Array
(
    [student_elements] => firstname,lastname,mobileno,age,gender
    [address_elements] => building,sector,city
    [marketing_elements] => 
    [office_use_elements] => counsellername,mobile,email
)
```

Now I pass the array value in explode function

```
$result_elements=explode(',',$get_elements);
```

Getting error

```
Severity: Warning
Message:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

I want to pass the `$result_elements` in foreach

```
$results = [];
foreach ($result_elements as $value) {
    echo $sql_elements_get="SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='".$value."'";
    $fetch_query = $this->db->query($sql_elements_get);
    foreach ($fetch_query->result() as $r){
        $results[] = $r;
    }
}
return $results;// I
```

I want to run the query each an every time to get the output of each value which coming from explode function.

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: You're passing an array into `explode`. You can't explode an array. You can only explode a string. The error message is telling you as much. You want to `explode` this: `$row->student_elements`, not `$get_elements`.

Comment: @deceze, Right, but I pass the $row->student_elements then I am getting the output only firstname,lastname,mobileno,age,gender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get a list of all unique elements in all of the strings. As others have mentioned, you cannot `explode` an array. One way you could loop through this would be to `implode` the array together, then `explode` it.

```
<?php
$get_elements = array (
    'student_elements'     => 'firstname,lastname,mobileno,age,gender',
    'address_elements'     => 'building,sector,city',
    'marketing_elements'     => NULL,
    'office_use_elements'     => 'counsellername,mobile,email'
);

// Combine all strings
$get_elements = implode(',',$get_elements);

// DEBUGGING ONLY
echo $get_elements;

// Split the elements
$get_elements = explode(',', $get_elements);

// DEBUGGING ONLY
echo '<pre>'.var_export($get_elements, TRUE).'</pre>';

// YOUR CODE
$results = [];
foreach ($get_elements as $value) {
    // Ensure it's not empty
    if($value != ''){
        echo $sql_elements_get="SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='".$value."'";
        $fetch_query = $this->db->query($sql_elements_get);
        foreach ($fetch_query->result() as $r){
            $results[] = $r;
        }
    }
}
return $results;

?>
```

A [Codepad](http://codepad.org/nWiPTuME) link for the output of your code (removing the database calls).

Answer (score 1):

Don't run so many queries; just run one.  Best practice is to always reduce your number of queries as low as possible.  Because you aren't distinguishing between the different values with the result elements, just one query using `IN` will be efficient.

```
$get_elements=[
    'student_elements'=>'firstname,lastname,mobileno,age,gender',
    'address_elements'=>'building,sector,city',
    'marketing_elements'=>'',
    'office_use_elements'=>'counsellername,mobile,email'
];

$values="'".str_replace(',',"','",implode(",",array_filter($get_elements,'strlen')))."'";

$fetch_query=$this->db->query("SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name IN ($values)");
foreach ($fetch_query->result() as $r){
    $results[] = $r;
}
```

*note, I filter out any empty strings before joining with comma, then wrap all values in single quotes.

---

To stress the importance of `IN` in the WHERE clause, here is the difference:

Without `IN` (assuming you filter out the empty elements) you make 11 calls to the database:

```
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='firstname'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='lastname'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='mobileno'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='age'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='gender'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='building'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='sector'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='city'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='counsellername'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='mobile'
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name='email'
```

With `IN` you make 1 call to the database:

```
SELECT fields_name, fields_type FROM `tbl_form_builder_fields` WHERE fields_name IN ('firstname','lastname','mobileno','age','gender','building','sector','city','counsellername','mobile','email')
```

Answer (score 0):

explode functions needs second parameters as a string not an array. You have to further drill down your array to obtain string

```
$get_elements = array(
    'student_elements' => $row->student_elements, 
    'address_elements' => $row->address_elements,  
    'marketing_elements' => $row->marketing_elements, 
    'office_use_elements' => $row->office_use_elements, 
);
for($get_elements as $key=>$value){
    $value = explode(',', $value);
  //run your query here
}
```

Comment: I got an error that syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';'

Comment: Its syntax error, you have written `for` loop instead of `foreach`